# Outlook "Highlighter" colors

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook, text-formatting, highlighting

I'm trying to change the colors that I can highlight text with in Microsoft Outlook, as they're pretty garish right now. Basically just trying to desaturate the colors or make them look more like pastels.

Thanks!

Comment: What highlighter do you mean and what's your Outlook version?

Comment: @thims: v 15.13.1 on OSX. here's a picture of what I'm trying to change [http://i.imgur.com/yTbsT3z.png](http://i.imgur.com/yTbsT3z.png)